# Compiling Qt 5.2.1 for win32-msvc fails due to Linker Errors

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile Qt 5.2.1 on a 64 Bit Win7 machine (I want 32 bit binaries).

I configured

```
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2012 -opengl desktop -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

and I did set the compiler path by running

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat
```

It compiles for a while but fails when linking.

This is the error output:

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /DLL /OUT:..\..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll @C:\Users\steffenh\AppData\Local\Temp\nm9509.tmp
   Creating library ..\..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.lib and object ..\..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.exp
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Accessible2_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleAction_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleApplication_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleComponent_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleEditableText_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleHyperlink_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleHypertext_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleImage_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleRelation_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleTable_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleTable2_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleTableCell_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleText_ProxyFileInfo
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AccessibleValue_ProxyFileInfo
..\..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 14 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

is there anyone who can help me?

best,
S.H

---

**UPDATE**

It seems that Qt tries to link against Microsoft Active Accessibility, whose main file is "oleacc.dll", located in the system path.

How can I check if this is for 32 bit or for 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

The linking worked when I added the VERBOSE linker flag via

"QMAKE_LFLAGS += /VERBOSE" to "mkspecs/qconfig.pri"

(This shouldn't change anything, but it worked).

Qt Bug Description is here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/QTBUG-37910/QTBUG-37910.html

Comment: I think that link is now: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37910  But yeah, that didn't work for me.